# Windows Phone 8 http request

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm wondering if there is some way to get the Urls what the user is browsing, somehow read the browser address bar for example after the user press go or enter.

I know that i can get the webpage content with WebClient() but is not what i'm looking for.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean from the IE-app or the webbrowser elemnent your can place in your app?

Comment: from the internet explorer APP, or whatever other web browser app.

Comment: What about the browser history? Is there any possibilities to read it some how?

Comment: No you cannot do that either. In Windows Phone you can't look at data from other apps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported API is available in WP8 for achieving this, You cannot access the internals of preloaded application from you app. If you are using Web browser control in you application, then you can access the navigated information for web browser's navigating event. This is the only way you can access the web related data.